# Description of preimage of $g$ defined by $g|_A = f|_A, g(S \setminus A) = \{x\}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

$S$ is a given directed set. $X$ is a **first countable** topological space. There is a function $f : S\rightarrow X$. With help of this $f$ , a new function $g:S\rightarrow X$ is being defined like the following :

$A\subset S$ is fixed.
$$g|_A=f|_A\\\text{and}\\g\left(S\backslash A\right)=\{x\}$$ for a fixed $x\in X.$

Now $U$ is a neighbourhood of $x$.

Then it says $$g^{-1}(U)=(S\backslash A)\bigcup \left(f^{-1}(U)\right)=S\backslash \left(A\backslash f^{-1}(U)\right)$$

This is the equation I cannot clearly understand.
I can see $g^{-1}(U)\subset (S\backslash A)\bigcup \left(f^{-1}(U)\right)$  but cannot understand the reverse of it. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x\in U,$ it should be clear from the definition of $g$ that $S\setminus A\subseteq g^{-1}[U].$ (Let me know if it isn't, and I'll expand.)

If $t\in f^{-1}[U],$ then either $t\in S\setminus A$ (in which case we've already handled it) or $t\in A$ and $f(t)\in U$, so that $g(t)\in U$ by definition of $g,$ and so $t\in g^{-1}[U].$ Thus, we also have $f^{-1}[U]\subseteq g^{-1}[U],$ proving the reverse inclusion.

As a side note, first-countability and directedness played no part, here.

Comment: Thanks. Actually that directedness and first countability were required for the entire theorem , it was just a small segment  , since I could not understand so thought may that would be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y \in (S\setminus A)\cup (f^{-1}(U))$. If $y \in S \setminus A$, then $g(y)=x \in U$, so $y \in g^{-1}(U)$. If $y \notin S\setminus A$, we have $y \in f^{-1}(U)$. Thus $f(y) \in U$. Since $y \notin S \setminus A$, $y \in S$ and we have $g(y)=f(y) \in U$. Hence $y \in g^{-1}(U)$ in this case as well. We conclude $(S \setminus A)\cup (f^{-1}(U))\subseteq g^{-1}(U)$.